# Getting audio file path on listview item click which is populated from Sqlite using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android

My app has a service which record incoming and outgoing calls and store files in application home directory and filepath, filename, duration, callType in Sqlite. In my MainActivity I have listview which is populated from Sqlite using SimpleCursorAdapter. Data is being stored and being shown in listview properly. 
**Problem**
I want user to click on a listitem and audio relating to this item should be played in separate Player activity. How can i acheive this?
Filepath is stored in Sqlite with each entry but I can't use listItem Display Text (Which is Caller Number) because there will be many cases that a number appeared many times in list. Can't use position property of listview item as _id of Sqlite because when an item is deleted, _id which is autoincrement will be different. I am confused here.

MainActivity.Java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvDate;
Button btnGet, btnShow;
ListView lv;
SharedPreferences prefs;
boolean isRunning = false;
DBSQL db;
TodoCursorAdapter adapter;
Cursor cursor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);


    db = new DBSQL(getApplicationContext());
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isRunning", isRunning);
    editor.commit();

    String currentTimeDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    tvDate.setText(currentTimeDate);


    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(db.getLogsCount() != 0){
                String fullData = db.getData();
                showMessage("Full Database", fullData);
            }else{
                showMessage("Full Database", "Database is empty.");
            }


        }
    });
}

public void populateListview(){
    db = new DBSQL(MainActivity.this);
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    String[] from = new String[]{"displayname", "fileduration", "filedatetime"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvNumber, R.id.tvDuration, R.id.tvDateTime};
    if (adapter == null){
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else {
        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    populateListview();
    super.onResume();
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.setting) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Setting.class));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.about) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "About Me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SQLite:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class DBSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="RecordedFiles";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="Files";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=3;

public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_FullName="filename";
public static final String KEY_ShortName="shortname";
public static final String KEY_DisplayName="displayname";
public static final String KEY_DateTime="filedatetime";
public static final String KEY_CallType="calltype";
public static final String KEY_Duration="fileduration";


private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public DBSQL(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_FullName + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_ShortName + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DisplayName + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DateTime + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_CallType + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_Duration + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public long addFile(String name, String duration, String datetime, String calltype) {
    ourDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    String shortName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    String[] split = shortName.split("-");
    String dispName = split[0];
    cv.put(KEY_FullName, name);
    cv.put(KEY_ShortName, shortName);
    cv.put(KEY_DisplayName, dispName);
    cv.put(KEY_DateTime, datetime);
    cv.put(KEY_CallType, calltype);
    cv.put(KEY_Duration, duration);
    long id = ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    return id;

}
public String getData() {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_ShortName , KEY_DisplayName, KEY_Duration, KEY_DateTime, KEY_CallType};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result="";

    int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    //int ifName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FullName);
    int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ShortName);
    int idur=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Duration);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DateTime);
    int iType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CallType);

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result= result + c.getString(iRow) + " "  + c.getString(iName) + " "
                + c.getString(idur) + " seconds \n" + c.getString(iDate) + " \n" + c.getString(iType) + " \n";
    }

    return result;
}


public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files", null);
    return cursor;
}




public String getSingleDisplayName(int id) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE id='" + id + "'", null);
    String result="";

    int iDName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DisplayName);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        result= result  + " " + c.getString(iDName) +  "\n";
    }

    return result;
}


public long getSingleFileDuration(int id) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE id='" + id + "'", null);
    long duration = 0;

    int iDur=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Duration);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        duration = c.getInt(iDur);
    }

    return duration;
}

public String getSingleFilePath(int id) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE id='" + id + "'", null);
    String fullName = "";

    int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FullName);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        fullName = c.getString(iName);
    }

    return fullName;
}

public String getSingleFileDateTime(int id) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE id='" + id + "'", null);
    String fullName = "";

    int iDateTime=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DateTime);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        fullName = c.getString(iDateTime);
    }

    return fullName;
}

public String getSingleCallType(int id) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Files WHERE id='" + id + "'", null);
    String callkiType = "";

    int iType=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CallType);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        callkiType = c.getString(iType);
    }

    return callkiType;
}

public void delteSingleEntry(String uniqueId) {
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        ourDatabase.execSQL("delete from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where uniqueid='" + uniqueId + "'");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("MyApp", e.toString());
    }



}


public int getLogsCount(){
    ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(ourDatabase, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    ourDatabase.close();
    return numRows;

}



}
```

Comment: generate a unique id for each recordings and store it in the data base while storing other data and on click of the list item get the unique id of the item, which is independent of id and  Caller Number

Comment: I created a unique id for every database entry but how can i get it through item? item is just a caller's number and it can be duplicated easily.

Comment: inside `onItemClick` call `Cursor c = (Cursor) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i); DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow(c);` what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: and if the data is correct simply pass the last parameter of `onItemClick` method to the `Player` activity

Comment: Thanx karthik and pskink. I got it working using this line.                      
Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: is the data correct? did you call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow(c)`? if so,  simply pass the last parameter of `onItemClick` method to the `Player` activity

Comment: Data is correct. Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position) gave me cursor set and i used this cursor set to extract "filepath" string and pass it to Player activity and use this "filepath" to play media file and delete it later. Its working perfectly. Thanx

Comment: no, just pass the **last** parameter of `onItemClick` method - you dont need to work with `Cursor` here - it was just to verify that data is ok, and in `Player` activity use `public Cursor getSingleFile(int id)` method to get all the data for given id

Comment: pskink, Why can't i get data from Cursor here in MainActivity and pass it to another activity? And can you help me out in my another problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821447/how-simplecursoradapters-bindview-works-and-how-to-implement-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by calling Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position) and it gave me Cursor set and i used this cursor set to get my file path to play audio file in my next activity.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
            filepath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("filename"));
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);
            it.putExtra("filepath", filepath);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```