# Change image according to value in a database field in SimpleCursorAdapter's bindView?

Tags: android

**Updated Answer**
I have a listview which is getting data from Sqlite Database using SimpleCursorAdapter. For this i created a custom TodoCursorAdapter class.

I am getting 3 field values from database using cursor and putting these values into 3 textviews using this Adapter and I want to get another field `callType` from Database, and, according to this field's value, I want to show a particular image in an imageview.

I want to show an image if `callType` value is `outgoing` and show another image if `callType` value is `incoming`. I tried to use if else in bindView but not working. Can you please point what i am missing here?

TodoCursorAdapter.java:

```
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Context appContext;
private int layout;
private Cursor cr;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.layout=layout;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.cr=c;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return inflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    view=inflater.inflate(layout, null, false);
    TextView tvNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
    TextView tvDuration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
    TextView tvDateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDateTime);
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2);

    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("displayname"));
    String duration = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fileduration")));
    String dateTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("filedatetime"));
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("calltype"));

    tvNumber.setText(number);
    tvDuration.setText(duration);
    tvDateTime.setText(dateTime);

    if (type.equals("incoming")){
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.incomingcall);
    }else {
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    db = new DBSQL(getApplicationContext());
    populateListview();

public void populateListview(){
    db = new DBSQL(MainActivity.this);
    cursor = db.getAllData();
    String[] from = new String[]{"displayname", "fileduration", "filedatetime"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvNumber, R.id.tvDuration, R.id.tvDateTime};
    if (adapter == null){
        adapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else {
        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    populateListview();
    super.onResume();
}


}
```

Comment: override `SimpleCursorAdapter#setViewImage` method

Comment: And where i need to do that? Here in my MainActivity where adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);                                                                          
 or I need to create another class extending SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: you can create another class extending SimpleCursorAdapter or create anonymous SimpleCursorAdapter class like: `new SimpleCursorAdapter(params, go, here) { ...`

Comment: Can you plz provide sample code for this or edit my code here?

Comment: so where is your custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: Fixed grammar. Formatted text

Comment: I am not using Custom SimpleCursorAdapter. Is it compulsory? Check  public void populateListview() method where i created SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: pskink, I updated my question with custom SimpleCursorAdapter. Please take a look

Comment: just override `setViewImage`, not `newView` and  `bindView`

Comment: pskink, How can i check value in setViewImage? Do i need to move my if else code piece to setViewImage? But where to get that "type" value to match?                                                                  if (type.equals("incoming")){
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.incomingcall);
    }else {
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing);
    }

Comment: did you override `setViewImage`? did you call `Log.d` to see what parameters it is called with?

Comment: Yes and it is working now. Thanx alot to you pskink. You must make your comment as answer and i will accept it as answer. You saved my time. Thanx again man

Comment: you can write a self answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. Thanx to pskink. I overrided setViewImage method and put a condition to check value and set image according to value.

```
@Override
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
    if (value.equals("incoming")){
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.incomingcall);
    }else {
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. Edited my answer.